# Any way to avoid SwiftUI GeometryReader preventing nested view to grow inside List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For some reason, putting a `GeometryReader` as an intermediary, kills geometry of its nested views if it's a `List` "cell".

Example code:

```swift
struct SampleView: View {
    var multilineText: some View {
        Text(
            """
            Some
            Amazing
            Multiline
            Copy
            """
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(1...5, id: \.self) { _ in
            GeometryReader { _ in
                self.multilineText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without `GeometryReader` (Expected) / Actual with `GeometryReader`:

[image]
[image]

This example, obviously, is over-simplified, but there is a legitimate reason to measure geometry for a nested view I'm building.

This is on Xcode 11 beta 6. Should I go straight into reporting this as a bug, or it's something expected and workable around?

Comment: I don’t know if it’s a bug, but I know that `GeometryReader` has added flexibility to otherwise inflexibly-sized subviews in all the betas. If you explain what you actually want to use `GeometryReader` for, maybe we can help you make it work better for you. For example, if you use the `GeometryReader` in an `overlay` or `background` modifier, the `GeometryReader` won’t be able to affect the layout of the modified view but will take on the modified view’s size.

Comment: @robmayoff I currently have a hex view, which uses `GeometryReader` on overlay to calculate size of a single monospace character, and compose an even set of columns, depending on a view's geometry according to the size of a single character. There is no way to build that without `GeometryReader`. But what stumbles me in general, I, as a consumer of some view, might not even know that it measures geometry, put it in a `List` - and boom, it's broken. Doesn't sound right to me tbh.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673501/77567) helps you.

Comment: I just hit this when I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474880/129889) to embed a multi-line UILabel in a List.

Comment: It seems odd to me that `GeometryReader` changes the behaviour of the nested item.  Since `GeometryReader` actual reads the container that holds it I've had luck with making it an empty sibling inside a `Group`.  `GeometryReader` seems especially weird inside of `ZStack`

Answer (score 2):

Add min row height for the list.

```
List(1...5, id: \.self) { _ in
    GeometryReader { _ in
        self.multilineText
    }
}.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 100)
```