# How can I get text to wrap in a UILabel (via UIViewRepresentable) without having a fixed width?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uilabel

Setting lineBreakMode to byWordWrapping and set numberOfLines to 0 does not seem to be sufficient:

```
struct MyTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "Here's a lot of text for you to display. It won't fit on the screen."
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UILabel, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct MyTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyTextView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 200))
    }
}
```

The text does not wrap, regardless of which setting I use for lineBreakMode. The canvas preview and live preview both look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the text not wrapping]

The closest I've gotten is setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth, which does cause the text to wrap, but there doesn't seem to be a value that means "whatever size the View is".

Comment: Could you include CardTextView code in your question please?

Comment: Whoops, I'd meant to rename that MyTextView like everywhere else. The example is self-contained. The only part of the file I didn't include was `import SwiftUI`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Possible solution is to declare the width as a variable on MyTextView:

```
struct MyTextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var width: CGFloat

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
        label.text = "Here's a lot of text for you to display. It won't fit on the screen."
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UILabel, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and then use GeometryReader to findout how much space there is avaible and pass it into the intializer:

```
struct ExampleView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            MyTextView(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, just to have in mind, when you use a ScrollView, looks like this solution doesn't work, just put the ScrollView inside the GeometryReader like this:
`var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                MarkDownText(width: geometry.size.width, string: self.documentationStr)
                    .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 10.0)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: What about **.attributedText**. Does it work with it too?

Comment: @MauricioZárate how can i do this with a system image beside it for both single and multi line

Comment: much appreciated, mate

Answer (score 23):

Try to use this magic line in makeUIView() func

```
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: yes but it's truncating line ! I've tried it, but I have only one line truncates at the end.

Comment: This solves a problem with my `UILabel` UIViewRepresentable when I use it to display only 1 line with `truncateTail`, if I don't use this line the label covers the width of the screen, now it uses the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`  as expected

Comment: This solution works for me! No need to provide `width` from GeometryReader as suggested by the accepted answer. You just need to set your label's numberOfLines to 0 and and this line.

Comment: This was also the one for me. I agree with @Thanh-NhonNguyen

Comment: This and `numberOfLines = 0` does the trick. No need for geometry reader.

Comment: This works perfectly and is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in a `ScrollView`. The accepted answer however does work in a `ScrollView`

Answer (score 5):

I found a somehow "nasty" approach that allows a `UILabel` to properly wrap when used as a `UIViewRepresentable` (*even when inside a `ScrollView`*), without the need for `GeometryReader`:

Whenever creating your `UILabel`:

```swift
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow,
                                              for: .horizontal)
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh,
                                for: .vertical)
```

This ensures that:

- the label will break line and not have an infinite width
- the label will not add grow unnecessarily in height, which may happen in some circumstances.

Then...

- Add a `width` property to your `UIViewRepresentable` that will be used to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`
- Use your `UIViewRepresentable` into a vanilla `SwiftUI.View`
- Add a `GeometryReader` as an overlay to prevent expansion
- Trigger the measurement after a soft delay, modifying some state to trigger a new pass.

*i.e.:*

```swift
    public var body: some View {
        MyRepresentable(width: $width,
                        separator: separator,
                        content: fragments)
            .overlay(geometryOverlay)
            .onAppear { shouldReadGeometry = true }
    }

    // MARK: - Private Props

    @State private var width: CGFloat?
    @State private var shouldReadGeometry = false

    @ViewBuilder
    var geometryOverlay: some View {
        if shouldReadGeometry {
            GeometryReader { g in
                SwiftUI.Color.clear.onAppear {
                    self.width = g.size.width
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### OLD ANSWER:

...

In your `updateUIView(_:context:)`:

```swift
if let sv = uiView.superview, sv.bounds.width != 0 {
    let shouldReloadState = uiView.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != sv.bounds.width
    uiView.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = sv.bounds.width
    if shouldReloadState {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
            self.stateToggle.toggle() // a Bool @State you can add in your struct
        }
    }
}
```

> ***Disclaimer:** I'm not a huge fan of `main.async` calls, particularly when they come in combination with some arbitrary delay, but this seems to get the work done in a consistent way.*

Comment: This does't seem to wrap past two lines

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon indeed, the previous solution didn't work for me under some extra scenarios after some testing. I've updated the answer with the current state of my workaround.

Comment: If you add the `@ViewBuilder` attribute to the `geometryOverlay` var it would use the view builder conditional block and you could remove both the return statements and the `eraseToAnyView()`.

Comment: @dktaylor good point, tweaked! Thank you.