# How to extract Hashtags from text using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any way to find ***Hashtags*** from a text with SwiftUI? 
This is how my try looks like:

calling the function like this :                         `Text(convert(msg.findMentionText().joined(separator: " "), string: msg)).padding(.top, 8)`
.
But it does not work at all.

My goal something like this: 
[image]

```
   extension String {
    func findMentionText() -> [String] {
        var arr_hasStrings:[String] = []
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(#[a-zA-Z0-9_\\p{Arabic}\\p{N}]*)", options: [])
        if let matches = regex?.matches(in: self, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
            for match in matches {
                arr_hasStrings.append(NSString(string: self).substring(with: NSRange(location:match.range.location, length: match.range.length )))
            }
        }
        return arr_hasStrings
    }
}
func convert(_ hashElements:[String], string: String) -> NSAttributedString {

    let hasAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]

    let normalAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

    let mainAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: normalAttribute)

    let txtViewReviewText = string as NSString

    hashElements.forEach { if string.contains($0) {
        mainAttributedString.addAttributes(hasAttribute, range: txtViewReviewText.range(of: $0))
        }
    }
    return mainAttributedString
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initailize `Text()` with a `String`, but instead you are attempting to initialize it with an `Array` of `String`.

You could either just display the first one if the array is not empty:

```
msg.findMentionText().first.map { Text($0) }
```

Or you could join the elements array into a single `String`:

```
 Text(msg.findMentionText().joined(separator: " "))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to improve the function to get like the example in the question ? With my try am I getting only the hashtags as output

Comment: I need like this: input : Hello #lulugaga how are you and the expected output how be something like this Hello *#lulugaga* how are you

Comment: Do you want to turn the hashtags into buttons inline with the rest of the text?

Comment: That is not currently possible in `SwiftUI`. To achieve this in `UIKit` you would have to use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I updated my Question, could you please take a look my this function calling does not work? : `Text(convert(msg.findMentionText().joined(separator: " "), string: msg)).padding(.top, 8)`

Comment: You need to use `NSAttributedString` with `UILabel` not 'Text` - I am sure that if you search SO you will find an example how to do it from SwiftUI.

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469001/how-can-i-get-text-to-wrap-in-a-uilabel-via-uiviewrepresentable-without-having

Comment: I did it, I have last question and I will accept your answer. The `Text(msg.findMentionText().joined(separator: " "))` gives me a string of hashtags how can I make each of them clickable with `button(action` ?

Comment: With this try `Button(action: {
                            print("go to the hashtags view")
                        }) {
                            Text(msg.findHashtags().joined(separator: " ").lowercased()).background(Color("bg"))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                        }` does not work because if I have #hi and #hello in the same sentence then both will be clickable.

Comment: You could try wrappng ForEach(msg.findMentionText()) { mention in Button // etc... } in a HStack or a VStack maybe?