# Size a UILabel in SwiftUI via UIViewRepresentable like Text to wrap multiple lines

Tags: ios, swiftui, uilabel, uiviewrepresentable

The goal is to get a `UILabel` integrated via `UIViewRepresentable` to size the same way `Text` does - use the available width and wrap to multiple lines to fit all the text thus increasing the height of the `HStack` it's in, instead of expanding in width infinitely. This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469001/how-can-i-get-text-to-wrap-in-a-uilabel-via-uiviewrepresentable-without-having), though the accepted answer does not work for the layout I'm using involving a `ScrollView`, `VStack`, and `HStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hello, World")
                    
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempor justo quam, quis suscipit leo sollicitudin vel.")
                    
                    //LabelView(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempor justo quam, quis suscipit leo sollicitudin vel.")
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Hello, World")
                    
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempor justo quam, quis suscipit leo sollicitudin vel.")
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LabelView>) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = text
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LabelView>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Using two Texts in the HStack results in this desired layout:
[image: Text and Text]

Using the Text and LabelView results in this undesired layout:
[image: Text and LabelView]

If you wrap the `LabelView` in `GeometryReader` and pass a `width` into `LabelView` to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, it's `0.0` for some reason. You can get a width if you move the `GeometryReader` outside the `ScrollView`, but then it's the scroll view width, not the width SwiftUI is proposing for the `LabelView` in the `HStack`.

If instead I specify `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)` it works better, but still doesn't display all the text, it strangely truncates the `LabelView` at 3 lines and the second `Text` at 2 lines.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem here is in `ScrollView` which requires definite height, but representable does not provide it. The possible solution is to dynamically calculate wrapped text height and specify it explicitly.

*Note: as height is calculated dynamically it is available only in run-time, so cannot be tested with Preview.*

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct LabelView: View {
    var text: String

    @State private var height: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        InternalLabelView(text: text, dynamicHeight: $height)
            .frame(minHeight: height)
    }

    struct InternalLabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
        var text: String
        @Binding var dynamicHeight: CGFloat

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

            return label
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
            uiView.text = text

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dynamicHeight = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: uiView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind checking my answer, as I'm not very familiar with UIKit especially with programatic creating views. Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to include `label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)` in `makeUIView` as well. This will try to hug the view, which is the same behavior from Text.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a concrete answer.

I've accidentally found that the fixed size modifier can help with auto resizing the UILabel to its content size.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let attributedString: NSAttributedString
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                RepresentedUILabelView(attributedText: attributedString)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 300)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .background(Color.orange.opacity(0.5))
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct RepresentedUILabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UILabel
    
    var attributedText: NSAttributedString
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        
        label.numberOfLines = 0
     
        label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

        label.textAlignment = .justified
        
        label.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
        
        // Compression resistance is important to enable auto resizing of this view,
        // that base on the SwiftUI layout.
        // Especially when the SwiftUI frame modifier applied to this view.
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        
        // Maybe this is not necessary.
        label.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return label
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        print(#fileID, #function)
        
        uiView.attributedText = attributedText
    }
    
}
```

Demo:

[image: A paragraph]

[image: A couple words]

---

In addition, if you do not wish to provide a max height. You can set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to your screen width. And if you put it i the updateUIView method, whenever the screen orientation changes, this method also get called.

```swift
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        
        uiView.attributedText = attributedText
        
        uiView.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 0.9 * UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
```

[image: Example, without max frame height.]

---

Just for completeness, this is the attributed text setting i used to test the view. However, it should not affect how the view resizing works.

```swift
func makeAttributedString(fromString s: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: s)
    
    let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paraStyle.alignment = .justified
    paraStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.25
    paraStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    paraStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0
    
    content.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                         value: paraStyle,
                         range: NSMakeRange(0, s.count))
    
    // First letter/word
    content.addAttributes([
        .font      : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: .bold),
        .expansion : 0,
        .kern      : -0.2
    ], range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
    
    return content
}

let coupleWords = "Hello, world!"

let multilineEN = """
    Went to the woods because I wished to live deliberately, to front only the essential facts of life, and see if I could not learn what it had to teach, and not, when I came to die, discover that I had not lived. I did not wish to live what was not life, living is so dear! Nor did I wish to practise resignation, unless it was quite necessary?"

    I went to the woods because I wished to live deliberately, to front only the essential facts of life, and see if I could.

    I went to the woods because I wished to live deliberately, to front only the essential facts of life, and see if I could not learn what it had to teach, and not.
    """
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the width constraint of the label. No need to tinker with content compression resistance or other label settings. Just set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` value:

```
public struct AttributedText: UIViewRepresentable {

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        let label = UIViewType()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {

    }

    public typealias UIViewType = UILabel
    public let attributedText: String
    public let width: CGFloat

    public init(attributedText: String, width: CGFloat) {
        self.attributedText = attributedText
        self.width = width
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
AttributedLabel(
    attributedText: someAttributedText,
    width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80
).padding(.bottom, -20)
```

You can provide the with `GeometryReader` or using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`. But there is some extra padding at the bottom. That is why I have used some negative bottom padding:

[image: Attributed text in SwiftUI]

Answer (score -4):

None of the solutions in the current answers are close enough to the essence of SwiftUI. Another way of thinking, since SwiftUI is good enough for Text, why not do something like this?

```
Text(yourstr)
 .foregroundColor(.clear) <<<<<<<--------
 .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
 .frame(maxWidth:.infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

 .overlay(
         Your ActiveLabelStack() <<<<<<<--------
                ,alignment: .center
            )
```

Simply put, let the Text tell you the height and be the base of the Label. After all, Text is the son of SwiftUI.